# AWS VPN Client fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn-client

using debian 12 + aws vpn client 3.9.0

this is the log

Any ideaaa ?

```
2023-10-20 10:38:51.769 -05:00 [DBG] Cancelling socket listen token
2023-10-20 10:38:51.769 -05:00 [DBG] Dispose socket
2023-10-20 10:38:51.769 -05:00 [DBG] Calling StopVpnAsync of GTK OpenVPN service to kill orphaned OpenVPN processes in case graceful shutdown failed
2023-10-20 10:38:51.770 -05:00 [DBG] Release process manager lock
2023-10-20 10:38:51.770 -05:00 [DBG] Process manager lock released more than once
2023-10-20 10:38:51.770 -05:00 [DBG] Received exception for connection state Disconnected. Show error message to user
2023-10-20 10:38:51.770 -05:00 [ERR] Exception received by connect window view model
Tmds.DBus.ConnectException: Connection refused awsvpnclient
 ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (111): Connection refused awsvpnclient
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Boolean flowContext)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectAsync(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketTaskExtensions.ConnectAsync(Socket socket, EndPoint remoteEP)
   at Tmds.DBus.Transports.TransportSocket.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endPoint)
   at Tmds.DBus.Transports.TransportSocket.ConnectUnixAsync(AddressEntry entry, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean supportsFdPassing)
   at Tmds.DBus.Transports.Transport.ConnectAsync(AddressEntry entry, ClientSetupResult connectionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Tmds.DBus.DBusConnection.ConnectAsync(ClientSetupResult connectionContext, Action`1 onDisconnect, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Tmds.DBus.Connection.DoConnectAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Tmds.DBus.Connection.DoConnectAsync()
   at Tmds.DBus.Connection.ConnectAsync()
   at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnGtkServiceClient.StopVpnAsync() in /home/ubuntu/Jenkins/workspace/GtkBuild/SecureConnectClient/ACVC.Core/OpenVpn/OvpnGtkServiceClient.cs:line 42
   at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnGtkProcessManager.Stop() in /home/ubuntu/Jenkins/workspace/GtkBuild/SecureConnectClient/ACVC.Core/OpenVpn/OvpnProcessManager.cs:line 861
   at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.GracefulKill() in /home/ubuntu/Jenkins/workspace/GtkBuild/SecureConnectClient/ACVC.Core/OpenVpn/OvpnConnectionManager.cs:line 1210
2023-10-20 10:38:51.776 -05:00 [DBG] Inserted event UI_APP_VPN_CONNECT_GENERAL_ERROR 1 to MetricsTable
2023-10-20 10:38:51.781 -05:00 [DBG] Inserted event UI_APP_VPN_CONNECT_GENERAL_ERROR 1 to AnalyticsTable
2023-10-20 10:38:51.786 -05:00 [DBG] Inserted event UI_APP_VPN_CONNECT_ATTEMPT_FAIL_UNCATEGORIZED_ERROR 1 to MetricsTable
2023-10-20 10:38:51.788 -05:00 [DBG] Inserted event UI_APP_VPN_CONNECT_ATTEMPT_FAIL_UNCATEGORIZED_ERR 1 to AnalyticsTable
2023-10-20 10:38:51.788 -05:00 [DBG] Disconnected
2023-10-20 10:38:51.790 -05:00 [DBG] Inserted event UI_APP_VPN_CONNECT_GENERAL_ERROR 0 to MetricsTable
2023-10-20 10:38:51.790 -05:00 [DBG] Shutting down metrics agent
2023-10-20 10:38:51.790 -05:00 [DBG] Metrics agent shut down
```

Comment: It says "Connection Refused". That could be a firewall on your side, or a typo. If you have a working configuration somewhere else try that exact configuration on this machine.

Comment: I don't think is that, because I had another machine with Debian 11 + AWS vpn client with 3.4.0 and is working ... both are in the same LAN. My suspect is that is something related with DNS ...

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit /etc/systemd/system/awsvpnclient.service to include `Environment=DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1`.

Full file is:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/awsvpnclient/Service/ACVC.GTK.Service
Restart=always
RestartSec=1s
User=root
Environment=DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also has to install http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1w-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb and http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1w-0+deb11u1_amd64.deb to deal with the openssl issue.

Credit for fix: https://repost.aws/questions/QUNJeF_ja_Suykous7EvfX5Q/aws-client-vpn-on-ubuntu-22-04#AN2pw6_MZ-SmefMHxWKI7m1g